# php timezone settings error

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have been trying to fix this error for a few days..

https://e-scapeps.com/vote/index.php

> Warning: main(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /home/escapeps/public_html/vote/templates/steps/step2.php on line 43
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: time in /home/escapeps/public_html/vote/templates/steps/step2.php on line 43
>
> Warning: main(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /home/escapeps/public_html/vote/templates/steps/step2.php on line 43
>
> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/escapeps/public_html/vote/templates/steps/step2.php on line 43

here is line 43 of step2.php

```
43: $time = time(true) - date.timezone($vote['callback_date']);
```

Thanks in advance, Any help here would be great.

just in case you need this: here is the entire step2.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST"
        || !isset($_POST['url'])
        || $_POST['url'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
    exit;
}

include '../../constants.php';
include '../../classes/class.database.php';

$db = new Database(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_data);

if (!$db->connect())
    exit;

if (!isset($_COOKIE['vote_user'])) {
    exit;
}

$username = filter_var($_COOKIE["vote_user"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$username = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/", '_', $username);

$sites = $db->getSites();

if ($sites == null) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">There are no sites to vote on!</div>';
    exit;
}

foreach ($sites as $site) {
    if ($site['active'] == false) {
        continue;
    }

    $url = str_replace("{sid}", $site['site_id'], $site['url']);
    $url = str_replace("{incentive}", str_replace(" ", "_", $username), $url);

    $vote = $db->getVote($site['id'], $username, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    if ($vote == null) {
        echo '<a class="btn btn-default site" target="_blank" href="vote.php?site='.$site['id'].'">'.$site['title'].'</a>';
    } else {
            if (!$db->connect())
    exit;

$votm = $db->getVotm();
$votes = $db->getVotes();

if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
{
    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

    
}
$time = time(true) - date.timezone($vote['callback_date']);
        $timeDiff = 43200 - $time;

        echo '<a class="btn btn-success site" target="_blank" href="#"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> '.formatSeconds($timeDiff).'</a>';
    }
}
?>

<hr style="border-color:transparent;">
Voting as <strong><?php echo str_replace("_", " ", $username); ?></strong>
```

Comment: [Edit] I added the line " date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");" but now i am getting this error : date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York"); 
Notice: Undefined variable: time in /home/escapeps/public_html/vote/templates/steps/step2.php on line 44

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/escapeps/public_html/vote/templates/steps/step2.php on line 44

Comment: [FIXED] line 43 should read : $time = time(true) - strtotime($vote['callback_date']);